# PHP rounding error

Tags: php, rounding, rounding-error

I'm using PHP 5.2.13 on my linux server. I'm getting weird error when rounding numbers. This is my test case:

```
<?php
echo "        " . round(1.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "       " . round(11.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "      " . round(111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "     " . round(1111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "    " . round(11111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "   " . round(111111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "  " . round(1111111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo " " . round(11111111.505, 2) . "\n";
echo "" . round(111111111.505, 2) . "\n";
```

This is results:

```
        1.51
       11.51
      111.51
     1111.51
    11111.51
   111111.51
  1111111.5
 11111111.51
111111111.51
```

Anyone knows what causes this? I can't update PHP, since it's shared server.

Comment: What does `sprintf('%.2f', $n)` return?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in PHP 5.2, because I can reproduce this on PHP 5.2.11 but not in any PHP 5.3 version.

Comment: did you observe that there are 7 digits in integer part in the erroneous line ?

Comment: @binaryLV sprintf produces: 1111111.50

Comment: Just reproduced this with most recent PHP 5.2 (5.2.17). Could not reproduce with 5.3.

Comment: @binaryLV if this reproduces in 5.2.17, I'm filing bug report. Thanks.

Comment: This is likely just a representational error. The offending value might internally simply exist as `1111111.5049999999`. Floating point values are inexact by nature. And PHP5.3 probably just has more heuristics.

Comment: else echo you can use str_pad()

Comment: Like mario said - `printf('%.10f', 1111111.505)` prints `1111111.5049999999`.

Comment: could not reproduce it with 5.3.2

Comment: PHP replied to the bug report that "This issue only affects PHP 5.2, which is not supported anymore". And indeed - when 5.2.16 was released, it was written that 5.2.16 release marks the end of support for PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the number 1111111.505 can't be represented exactly in floating point notation.  The closest it can get is 1111111.5049999999.  So what ends up happening is that it converts the number in your code to 1111111.50499999999 and then it does the rounding.  Which results in 1111111.5.  Floating point numbers have problems in that they can't represent a lot of even seemingly simple decimal numbers with complete accuracy.  For instance. the number 0.1 cannot be accurately represented using binary floating numbers.  Using Python, if you type in 0.1, it returns 0.10000000000001. Plus or minus a few zeros.  This is the reason that some languages such as .Net provide a "Decimal" data type which is able to represent all decimal values within a certain range and number of decimal places.  The downside of the decimal data type is that it is slower, and each number takes more space to store.

Comment: You mention Python, but is there a way around this for PHP? Is there a PHP Decimal class?

Comment: Best option for PHP is represent decimals as strings and use BCMath extension.

Answer (score 8):

If still somebody reach this page with similar problems where floating number subtraction causes error or strange values. 
I want to explain this problem with a bit more details. The culprit is the floating point numbers. 
To illustrate the problem, I will explain why with a simple example and you can assume from there why it affecting rounding etc.

It is not directly related to PHP and it is not a bug. 
However, every programmer should be aware of this issue.

This problem even took many lives two decades ago.

On 25 February 1991 this problem in floating number calculation in a MIM-104 Patriot missile battery prevented it intercepting an incoming Scud missile in Dhahran, Saudi Arabia, contributing to the death of 28 soldiers from the U.S. Army's 14th Quartermaster Detachment.

But why it happens?

The reason is that floating point values represent a limited precision. So, a value might 
not have the same string representation after any processing. It also
includes writing a floating point value in your script and directly 
printing it without any mathematical operations.

Just a simple example:

```
$a = '36';
$b = '-35.99';
echo ($a + $b);
```

You would expect it to print 0.01, right? 
But it will print a very strange answer like 0.009999999999998

Like other numbers, floating point numbers double or float is stored in memory as a string of 0's and 1's. How floating point differs from integer is in how we interpret the 0's and 1's when we want to look at them. There are many standards how they are stored.

Floating-point numbers are typically packed into a computer datum as the sign bit, the exponent field, and the significand or mantissa, from left to right....

Decimal numbers are not well represented in binary due to lack of enough space. So, uou can't express 1/3 exactly as it's 0.3333333..., right? Why we can't represent 0.01 as a binary float number is for  the same reason. 1/100 is 0.00000010100011110101110000..... with a repeating 10100011110101110000.

If 0.01 is kept in simplified and system-truncated form of 01000111101011100001010 in binary,when it is translated back to decimal, it would be read like 0.0099999.... depending on system (64bit computers will give you much better precision than 32-bits). Operating system decides in this case whether to print it as it sees or how to make it in more human-readable way. So, it is machine-dependent how they want to represent it. But it can be protected in language level with different methods.

If you format the result, echo number_format(0.009999999999998, 2);  it will print 0.01.

It is because in this case you instruct how it should be read and how precision you require. 
References: [1](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa10/notes/07.1_FloatingPoint/Patriot.html?CurrentSlide=10),[2](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold//disasters/Patriot-dharan-skeel-siam.pdf),[3](http://fas.org/spp/starwars/gao/im92026.htm),[4](http://seeri.etsu.edu/SECodeCases/ethicsC/PatriotMissile.htm),[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: From how I understand it, the missile failure had nothing to do with the floating point precision but with the missile's internal clock https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIM-104_Patriot

Comment: Dig deeper to understand how that that internal clock was working. This example is taught at universities with its original source code for illustration.
"Because of the way the Patriot computer performs its calculations and the fact that its registers are only 24 bits long, the conversion of time from an integer to a real number cannot be any more precise than 24 bits". 
https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa10/notes/07.1_FloatingPoint/Patriot.html?CurrentSlide=10

Comment: "The computer's registers were only 24 bits long. This and the consistency in the time lags suggested that the error was caused by a fixed-point 24-bit representation of 0.1 in base 2. The base 2 representation of 0.1 is nonterminating; for the first 23 binary digits after the binary point, the value is
0.1 ! (1 - 2-20). The use of 0.1 ! (1 - 2-20) in obtaining a floating-point value of time in seconds would
cause all times to be reduced by 0.0001%."
http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold//disasters/Patriot-dharan-skeel-siam.pdf
This problem is widely studied at software testing subjects at most unis

Comment: If you prefer wikipedia as a reliable source which I can tell from your link, you can see that problem being discussed under floating point in the same "reliable source": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarification. I don't prefer wikipedia - was just the first that popped up when i googled the name of the missile and "saudi arabia". no offense meant

Answer (score 3):

You need tp upgrade the wetwaer - not the PHP version.

> echo "        " . round(1.505, 2) . "\n";

You seem to think you're asking PHP to return the rounded value of 1.505 - but its actually **got** to return the decimal version of the rounded version of the binary version of 1.505

Try entering the numbers [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html) and have a look at the binary representations.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like you're running into an [accuracy problem caused by using floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Floats are not guaranteed to be completely accurate and you may find that this problem manifests on one system but not on another.

If you really care about precision with arbitrary floating-point numbers, use [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) or [gmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) if one is available, though if using bcmath, you'll need to make a bcround() function. The only one I've found which actually works is posted in the comments of the php.net [bcscale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) page:

```
function bcround($number, $scale=0) {
        $fix = "5";
        for ($i=0;$i<$scale;$i++) $fix="0$fix";
        $number = bcadd($number, "0.$fix", $scale+1);
        return    bcdiv($number, "1.0",    $scale);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this. Same thing happens in JS. The boundary happens with decimals above 16383, which as an integer is `11111111111111` in binary, and below 32767, which is `111111111111111` in binary. Compare: `(32767.505).toFixed(2)` ("32767.51") vs `(32768.505).toFixed(2)` ("32768.50"). If you need to stay to 2 digits of precision and can't use the above libraries, consider multiplying everything by 100 (do your math in pennies rather than dollars).

Answer (score 1):

@Shabbyrobe: your function is wrong: try to round this number with a scale of 2: 44069.3445

it should be 44069.35, but default php round()- and your Function returns 44069.34

Working code by a member of php.net:

```
function mround($number, $precision=0) {

$precision = ($precision == 0 ? 1 : $precision);   
$pow = pow(10, $precision);

$ceil = ceil($number * $pow)/$pow;
$floor = floor($number * $pow)/$pow;

$pow = pow(10, $precision+1);

$diffCeil     = $pow*($ceil-$number);
$diffFloor     = $pow*($number-$floor)+($number < 0 ? -1 : 1);

if($diffCeil >= $diffFloor) return $floor;
else return $ceil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4921809/3271972) of Shabbyrobe does not handle negative numbers.
This is a working improvement of the code, which handles negative numbers as well as the default scale:

```
function bcround($number, $scale = null) {
    if (is_null($scale)) {
        $scale = bcscale();
    }
    $fix = ($number < 0) ? '-' : '';
    $fix .= '0.' . str_repeat('0', $scale) . '5';
    $number = bcadd($number, $fix, $scale + 1);
    return bcdiv($number, "1.0", $scale);
}
```